# Two <li> elements on page, with different styles

Tags: html, css, django, styling

I am making site with Django and i am overlapping < li > stylings on site. For my Menu at top of page i have one file **navigation.html** with styling **navigation.css** but for my front page i have **index.html** with styling **style.css**. When i use them separately i can see everything works fine, but when i include navigation into my index page with -

```
{% include "app/navigation.html" %}
```

command, all < li > elements looks the same as **navigation.css** would be used for all page, but i need **navigation.css** to be used only on sites navigation, not rest of the page.

Here is my code structure:

**Index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/style.css' %}" />
{% include "polls/components/navigation.html" %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">something something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nothing nothing</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

**Navigation.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/navigation.css' %}" />
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

I think there could be 2 ways to solve it, but i don't know how in ether way.

1. Somehow i need to make that **navigation.css** only can style **navigation.html** file.
2. In **index.html** i need to insert some command that can separete li element styling for different parts.

Its probable simple, but i am beginner so it would be good if someone can share wisdom.

Comment: You could add a class or id to your ul/li and write css based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put each menu inside a div that applies to only that menu and then in your css change it accordingly.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/x3ftr1t0/) showing what i mean.

example html div wraping different menus

```
<p>nav type a</p>
<div id="nav-a">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">nav type a</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">nav type a</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
<p>nav type 2</p>
<div id="nav-b">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">nav type b</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">nav type b</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

example css that only applies styling to the li elements inside the specified div id

```
#nav-a ul li{
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav-b ul li{
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: will there be some disadvantage if i will wright `<li class=li-1> sample </li>` and in css `.li-1 { color: red; }` insted of using id? i am not familiar with id but i can learn if it has advantage.

Comment: you can give each li its own class that way yes or even just give the div wrapping the li's a class rather than id to get the same result

Answer (score 0):

overlapping is quite probable.
As in a html page last imported css will always override previous css so just try to separate your navigation.html li tag & index.html li tag by providing them a class and apply css on their class.

```
nav.html


    <ul class = 'nav'>
    <li>something </il>
    <li> lorem </li>
    </ul>

nav.css

    .nav li
    {
    /*css goues here*/
    }


similarly for index.html
    <ul class = 'index'>
    <li>something </il>
    <li> lorem </li>
    </ul>

index.css

    .index li
    {
    /*css goues here*/
    }
```